# VBscript results to PHP variable

Tags: php, vbscript

I’m trying to send the results of Vb script to a PHP variable,
The code get the CN name in AD.

My Vb code is below:

```
Set objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objADSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
objUser.CN
```

How can I send the code to my  PHP file as a variable once the webpage is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ADO Recordset as a wrapper

```
Set objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objADSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
objUser.CN
ret = send2PHP("yourpage.php?data=", strUser)


function send2PHP(phpURL, data)
  on error resume next                        ' if your php page returns a valid recorset you can omit 'on error
  set rsPHP = wscript.createobject("adodb.recordset")
'here you must serialize "data" to be a valid uri value (not done here)                    '
  rsPHP.open phpURL & data ,,,, 256           ' this statment (and the following ones)        '
  if not rsPHP.eof then send2PHP = rsPHP(0)   ' fails if you do not return a valid recordset  '
  rsPHP.close                                 ' form php script, but at least you             '
  set rsPHP = nothing                         ' have the "data" within the php anyway         '
end function
```